# How to generate a manifest file for splash screen?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-manifest, splash-screen

I want to add an animated **splash screen to my flutter app** ! Is there any splash screen generator that I can use ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you can use any of these plugins
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash
https://pub.dev/packages/splash